# Installed kdenlive twice using apt then flatpack, terminal and software app telling me different version? Why?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kdenlive, flatpak

First I installed Kdenlive using `apt-get intall kdenlive`, this installed version *17.12.3*

Knowing some features're not available, I was gonna upgrading Kdenlive using `flatpak`, using following command:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install --from https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.kde.kdenlive.flatpakref
```

This successfully installed kdenlive version *19.12.3*

Question:

1. When I run `kdenlive -v` on terminal, it says *17.12.3*, but when I opened kdenlive and go to help->about it says version *19.12.3*, so did I have two kdenlive version installed?
2. If yes, how can I remove the older one? `sudo apt-get remove kdenlive`?
3. Was the correct way to upgrade software ver? How to properly upgrade if they belong to different repo/package manager?

*P.S: still a linux noob*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When I run `kdenlive -v` on terminal, it says *17.12.3*, but when I opened kdenlive and go to help->about it says version *19.12.3*, so did I have two kdenlive version installed?

   > Yes. You first installed version 17.12.3 using `apt`, then installed version 19.12.3 using `flatpak`.
2. If yes, how can I remove the older one? `sudo apt-get remove kdenlive`?

   > Yes. Simply run the following command to remove the older (apt) version:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt remove kdenlive
   > ```
3. Was the correct way to upgrade software ver? How to properly upgrade if they belong to different repo/package manager?

   > No. That's not the correct way to '*upgrade*'. As hinted before `apt` and `flatpak` work independently. You can install two instances of the same application using these package managers.
   >   To update packages installed using `apt`, run
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
   > ```
   >
   > To packages installed using `flatpak`, run
   >
   > ```
   > flatpak update
   > ```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is it correct that I think it's not possible to upgrade the version to 19.12.3 using `apt`, because the only Kdenlive version in `apt` repo is ver 17.12.3?

Comment: Yes, you can only update to *latest version available in the repo*.